# Firefox extension to hide some elements permanently

Tags: firefox

This extension already existed with a name [element hiding helper](https://adblockplus.org/elemhidehelper). But it's not supported by my version of the browser.

I have found [lizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lizardextension/). It's great, but I would like to hide (remove) some elements permanently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the uBlock Origin ad blocker add-on. You can choose to block addons using the element picker tool, or just right click the element > Block element and then adjust the sliders and follow the UI. Other ad blockers also have similar features.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Click to Remove Element" (CTRE):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/click-to-remove-element-ff/